# SharedPreferences getInt() returning 0 all the time

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having trouble understanding why my code won't work. For some reason, the key "karma" doesn't seem to be found and then it sets this.karmaPoints back to 0 when the debugger reaches this line: "this.karmaPoints = settings.getInt("karma", 0);"

```
public void incrementKarmaPoints(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("karma", this.karmaPoints++);
    editor.commit();
}

public int getKarmaPoints(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.karmaPoints = settings.getInt("karma", 0);
    return karmaPoints;
}
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Is your context variable the same?

Comment: is context difference really that great a difference

Comment: try  this.karmaPoints+=1 instead or prefix

Comment: The context variable is the same. It was actually what @Remario suggested. Thank you for everyone that responded quickly :)

Comment: PREFS_NAME, whats the value?

Comment: First of all, commit() is deprecated; use apply(). Then consider using the defaultSharedPreference as suggested below;

Comment: @Remario, PREFS_NAME is a final variable that I set to "CAPSTONE_APP"

Comment: @Eenvincible, thanks! I'll make sure to change everything to .apply()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is actually simple, just like i said in comment, In Post-Increment value is first used in a expression and then incremented.

```
public void incrementKarmaPoints(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
    this.karmaPoints+=1; // or ++this.karmaPoints
    editor.putInt("karma",this.karmaPoints );
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: either do that or prefix increment

Comment: so it will be always be zero, since it is never incremented

Comment: I'd suggest to also use `apply()` rather than `commit()`

Comment: yes, it delays writing to disk until better time, but safely saves in memory. You could update your answer to use apply :)

Comment: i just checked the documentation it does not say it was deprecated, explain that

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()

Answer (score 2):

I guess `this.karmaPoints` is 0 at the beginning. When you are trying to save `this.karmaPoints++` it means you are passing the value of 0 into editor and incrementing the value only after.
For example try to set the value of `this.karmaPoints` to 10. 
And change `this.karmaPoints++` to `++this.karmaPoints`

Comment: yea i suspected this, i had suggested it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach; use default preference

```
public static void storeValueInSharedPrefs(Context context, String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    //as pointed out below by the other guys; increment before storing 
    //the value in preferences
    int karma = karma + 1;
    editor.putInt(key, karma);

    editor.apply();
}
```

Then fetch or read it like this:

```
public static int getValueFromSharedPrefs(String key, Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    return preferences.getInt(key, 0);
}
```

Then make sure your context is not null and realize here that we are using `defaultSharedPreferences`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: this does not answer the question,

Comment: Not only it doesn't answer the question, but it also contains the same error as in OP's question: using postfix ++ operator instead of a prefix one.